bcprov-jdk18on 1.74 upgrade failing with jcajcehelper no class found error
We bcprov-jdk16 1.44 and bcprov-jdk14 1.47 in my project pom.xml file.
as part of OSS upgrade, I have removed above jars and added bcprov-jdk18 1.74 version.
after that I am getting

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jcajce.JcaJceHelper

and I could not see any existing artifact in my pom file for bcpkix-jdk18. so ff I add bcpikx-jdk18 1.74 in my pom, does this issue get resolved?
added bcprov-jdk15 version but got import exception in pge encrypting.
need to solve no class found exception with using bcprov-jdk18 1.74 version.

Why not just try it and see if it works?

After this change also we have same error.  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jcajce.JcaJceHelper  any suggestions please
